# How to start delayed job workers in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, production-environment

I was following [railscast for delayed job](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job). Things are working perfectly on my machine. How can start delayed_job workers in production mode?

I am using [delayed_job gem,(2.1.4)](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

Comment: `foreman start`

Check out this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13431483/539075

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

For Rails 4

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

Solved my problem.

It may give you an error that tmp directory doesn't exists. Just create one and run previous command again..

Comment: Hi, I use the code above and nothing happen. Do you do other configuration as well?

Comment: @shoujo_sm Nopes. It will just run the delayed job. Check delayed Job webview to understand is there any worker working on not. This command will come back to terminal itself and will run a process in background.

Comment: RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start for rails 4

Answer (score 3):

You can try to run the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production cd ~/path_to_your_app/current && /usr/local/bin/ruby ./script/delayed_job start
```

where you should adjust `/usr/local/bin/ruby` based on your production server ruby configuration.

Comment: This is a better example of what you should run on production (since it'll likely be run through a script)  +1