# Ruby on Rails Delayed Job Local Wont Run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm working with delayed job for active record gem https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job  I'm trying to set up a job to run five minutes after an event occurs in my application.  After five minutes passes, I need to make some database updates.  I've tried rake jobs:work and RAILS_ENV=development script/delayed_job start. Prior to this all, I have run bundle install, rails generate delayed_job:active_record, and rake db:migrate.  I have a lottery website that needs to check winners every five minutes and update tokens for winning players.

I wait five minutes, but no updates are made in my local application.

Here's what I have so far:

Gem File:

```
 gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

 gem "daemons"
```

Job (located in lib)

```
class WinnersJob < Struct.new(:blast_id)
def perform
      ...
    end
```

Controller

```
 require 'winners'
 Delayed::Job.enqueue(WinnersJob.new(blast.id), 1, 5.minutes.from_now)
 end
```

Answer (score 13):

I think you have to launch the background workers locally using foreman. The following worked on my Mac.

From Heroku docs:

You then need to tell your application to process jobs put into your job queue, you can do that by adding this to your `Procfile`:

```
worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Now when you start your application using Foreman it will start processing your job queue.

```
foreman start
```

Having said all that, unless you are deploying on a Mac, it doesn't really matter if they run locally. (I noticed this ***after*** I got it working.) It only matters if it works on your servers. If you are deploying on Heroku, then Delayed Job works well.

Reference:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: `bundle exec rake jobs:workoff` to run pending jobs and exit