# Ruby on Rails Job Scheduling Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm going to try again after my hiccup last night.  The following is what I'm trying to find a solution to:  After conditions in my controller are met, I need to run a job five minutes later.  This is for a lottery website for a mmo.  After a ticket is sold, based on specific conditions(player amount met, amount of lottery item met), players have five minutes to buy a tickets.  After five minutes, I need to pick random unique ticket numbers and award winners tokens.  Right now I run this manually.  I'm looking for a solution that I can schedule in my controller to run five minutes later.

I have tried delayed_job which I cannot get to work locally on a mac. [Ruby on Rails Delayed Job Local Wont Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416439/ruby-on-rails-delayed-job-local-wont-run)  I have tried iron.io paid solution with no luck.

Please offer suggestions with possible tutorials.

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler or the new kid sidekiq wich seems to have native scheduling on it.https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidekiq is *great* and you should try it first.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

Mike Perham, the lead author, is a terrific programmer and he writes about comparisons among Sidekiq, Resque, Delayed Job.

Worth reading his blog post about it here:

http://www.mikeperham.com/2011/05/04/background-processing-vs-message-queueing/

Comment: Thanks. I got it working locally. Just need to figure out how to keep Sidekiq running in prod on passenger