# Rails delayed job and docker: adding more workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, delayed-job

I run my rails app using a Docker. Delayed jobs are processed by a single worker that runs in a separate container called `worker` and inside it worker runs with a command `bundle exec rake jobs:work`.

I have several types of jobs that I would like to move to a separate queue and create a separate worker for that. Or at least have two workers for process tasks.

I tried to run my worker container with `env QUEUE=default_queue bundle exec rake job:work && env QUEUE=another_queue bundle exec rake job:work` but that does not make any sense. It does not fails, is starts but jobs aren't processed.

Is there any way to have separate workers in one container? And is it correct? Or should I create separate container for each worker I would ever want to make?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running the command `command1 && command2` results in command2 being executed only when command1 completes. rake jobs:work never terminates, even when it has finished executing all the jobs in the queue, so the second command will never execute.

A single "&" is probably what you're looking for: `command1 & command2`.
This will run the commands independently in their own processes.

You should use the delayed_job script on production, and it's a good idea to put workers of different queues into different containers in case one of the queues contains jobs that use up a lot of resources.

This will start a delayed job worker for the default_queue:
`bundle exec script/delayed_job --queue=default_queue start`
For Rails 4, it is: `bundle exec bin/delayed_job --queue=default_queue start`
Check out this answer on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6814591/6006050

You can also start multiple workers in separate processes using the -n option. This will start 3 workers in separate processes, all picking jobs from the default_queue:
`bundle exec script/delayed_job --queue=default_queue -n 3 start`

Differences between `rake jobs:work` and the delayed_job script:
It appears that the only difference is that `rake jobs:work` starts processing jobs in the foreground, while the delayed_job script creates a daemon which processes jobs in the background. You can use whichever is more suited to your use case.
Check this github issue: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/659

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it soon. As far as I'm not mature user of Rails, can you please, say (or give a link to) what's the difference between running `rake jobs:work` and `script/delayed_job ..`? Also, in my project there's no `script` folder. I didn't do it myself from scratch, i just supporting the project, so i don't know why it's so...

Comment: Edited my answer to add the difference between rake jobs:work and the delayed_job script. Also added that for rails 4 it should be `bin/delayed_job` instead of `script/delayed_job`.

Comment: thank a lot! now I see all this. And.. Am I right: in case, `rake` run it in foreground, we can't run several workes just like for `bin/d_j` using `-n`? I mean not using _exactly_ `-n` but smth similar to.

Comment: No, I don't think `rake jobs:work` has any option to automatically create multiple workers. You could do `rake jobs:work & rake jobs:work & rake jobs:work`.   
A better solution might be to do `bin/delayed_job -n 3 run`. Using "run" instead of "start" causes it to run in the foreground.

Comment: Thank you one more time. Now I fell more confident about all that, but still feel like I have to read docs more careful :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually i just came across this problem with scaling delayed_jobs on docker

see this gist for a script that starts delayed jobs with arbitrary arguments and listens to SIGTERM and executes a smooth shutdown of the started jobs on container shutdown. This way you can execute as many processes and queues as you want.

https://gist.github.com/jklimke/3fea1e5e7dd7cd8003de7500508364df

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variable DELAYED_JOB_ARGS contains the arguments for delayed jobs for, e.g. defining queues and worker pools.

# function that is called when the docker container should stop. It stops the delayed job processes
_term() {
  echo "Caught SIGTERM signal! Stopping delayed jobs !"
  # unbind traps
  trap - SIGTERM
  trap - TERM
  trap - SIGINT
  trap - INT
  # end delayed jobs 
  bundle exec "./bin/delayed_job ${DELAYED_JOB_ARGS} stop"

  exit
}

# register handler for selected signals
trap _term SIGTERM
trap _term TERM
trap _term INT
trap _term SIGINT

echo "Starting delayed jobs ... with ARGs \"${DELAYED_JOB_ARGS}\""

# restart delayed jobs on script execution
bundle exec "./bin/delayed_job ${DELAYED_JOB_ARGS} restart"

echo "Finished starting delayed jobs... Waiting for SIGTERM / CTRL C"

# sleep forever until exit
while true; do sleep 86400; done
```